# PFQuery's hasCachedResults always returns NO, even if it ends up using a cached result

Tags: objective-c, caching, parse-platform, pfquery

I use a query to fill in a value on a cell and cache it to avoid making multiple network calls when cell is reused. I animate a value in based off the response of the query.

No matter what I try I can't get the animation to only occur if its a network response. I know I'm getting cached results because the value animates instantly any time I scroll to that cell after the first time. (I also set it up to cache anyway, but this corroborates that I did it correctly).

Is there a special way you are supposed to be using hasCachedResults?

NOTE: It has nothing to do with the fact that I'm using `objectWithoutData` and doing a relationship query. See link below under EDIT for more information

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:...];
    PFRelation *relation = [obj relationForKey:...];
    PFQuery *q = [relation query];
    [q whereKey:...];

// CHECKING TO SEE IF CACHED
    if ([q hasCachedResult]) {
        NSLog(@"1");
    }

    q.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork; // to prevent network calls every time cell is re-used.

// CHECKING TO SEE IF CACHED        
    if ([q hasCachedResult]) {
        NSLog(@"2");
    }


    [q countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError * _Nullable error) {

// CHECKING TO SEE IF CACHED            
        if ([q hasCachedResult]) {
            NSLog(@"3");
        }
    }
```

Neither 1, 2, or 3 get printed.

## EDIT

This *may* be a bug (or at least unclear documentation). I looked into it a little more, I included a lot more information here: [Issue on Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/623)